# Binary tree array to in-order Binary tree array

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, inorder

I am solving one of the HackerEarth problem . And problem statement is as follows,

Given a complete binary tree with N nodes and each node have an distinct integer **ai** attached with it, find the minimum number of swaps you can make to convert the binary tree into binary search tree. In one swap, you can select any two nodes and swap their values.

You will be given the array representation of the binary tree. Root of the tree will be at **a[1]** Left child of root will be at **a[2]** and right child of root will be at a3. Left child of node at array position **k** will be at **a[2∗k]** and right child of node at array position k will be at **a[2∗k+1]**.

Question is how to convert  given array into in-order array of the tree.I tried following code. On web i did't found any link.

```
static void inOrderArr(int destIndex,int index, int[] source, int[] dest) {
    int leftIndex = (index ) * 2;
    int rightIndex = (((index ) * 2) + 1);

    if(leftIndex<source.length){
        inOrderArr(destIndex,leftIndex, source,dest);
    }
    System.out.println(index);
    dest[destIndex++] = source[index-1];
    if(rightIndex<source.length){
        inOrderArr(destIndex,rightIndex, source,dest);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following solution and it worked.

```
private static void inorderTraversal(int array[], int pos, Node[] nodes) {
    if (pos >= array.length) {
        return;
    }
    inorderTraversal(array, 2 * pos + 1, nodes);
    nodes[Node.count] = new Node(array[pos], Node.count);
    Node.count++;
    inorderTraversal(array, 2 * pos + 2, nodes);
}
```

Here is the Node type declaration

```
static private class Node implements Comparable<Node> {

    private static int count = 0;

    public Node(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Node(int value, int position) {
        this(value);
        this.position = position;
    }

    private int value;
    private int position;
    private boolean visited;

    public boolean isVisited() {
        return visited;
    }

    public void markVisited() {
        visited = true;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Node o) {
        if (this.value >= o.value) {
            return 1;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

The idea is to use the fact that inorder traversal of Binary Search Tree is in increasing order of their value.So, find the inorder traversal of the Binary Tree and store it in the array and try to sort the array.

Here is the code in c to convert given array into in-order array of the tree.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define bool int

/* A binary tree tNode has data, pointer to left child
   and a pointer to right child */
struct tNode
{
   int data;
   struct tNode* left;
   struct tNode* right;
};

/* Structure of a stack node. Linked List implementation is used for 
   stack. A stack node contains a pointer to tree node and a pointer to 
   next stack node */
struct sNode
{
  struct tNode *t;
  struct sNode *next;
};

/* Stack related functions */
void push(struct sNode** top_ref, struct tNode *t);
struct tNode *pop(struct sNode** top_ref);
bool isEmpty(struct sNode *top);

/* Iterative function for inorder tree traversal */
void inOrder(struct tNode *root)
{
  /* set current to root of binary tree */
  struct tNode *current = root;
  struct sNode *s = NULL;  /* Initialize stack s */
  bool done = 0;

  while (!done)
  {
    /* Reach the left most tNode of the current tNode */
    if(current !=  NULL)
    {
      /* place pointer to a tree node on the stack before traversing 
        the node's left subtree */
      push(&s, current);                                               
      current = current->left;  
    }

    /* backtrack from the empty subtree and visit the tNode 
       at the top of the stack; however, if the stack is empty,
      you are done */
    else                                                             
    {
      if (!isEmpty(s))
      {
        current = pop(&s);
        printf("%d ", current->data);

        /* we have visited the node and its left subtree.
          Now, it's right subtree's turn */
        current = current->right;
      }
      else
        done = 1; 
    }
  } /* end of while */ 
}     

/* UTILITY FUNCTIONS */
/* Function to push an item to sNode*/
void push(struct sNode** top_ref, struct tNode *t)
{
  /* allocate tNode */
  struct sNode* new_tNode =
            (struct sNode*) malloc(sizeof(struct sNode));

  if(new_tNode == NULL)
  {
     printf("Stack Overflow \n");
     getchar();
     exit(0);
  }            

  /* put in the data  */
  new_tNode->t  = t;

  /* link the old list off the new tNode */
  new_tNode->next = (*top_ref);   

  /* move the head to point to the new tNode */
  (*top_ref)    = new_tNode;
}

/* The function returns true if stack is empty, otherwise false */
bool isEmpty(struct sNode *top)
{
   return (top == NULL)? 1 : 0;
}   

/* Function to pop an item from stack*/
struct tNode *pop(struct sNode** top_ref)
{
  struct tNode *res;
  struct sNode *top;

  /*If sNode is empty then error */
  if(isEmpty(*top_ref))
  {
     printf("Stack Underflow \n");
     getchar();
     exit(0);
  }
  else
  {
     top = *top_ref;
     res = top->t;
     *top_ref = top->next;
     free(top);
     return res;
  }
}

/* Helper function that allocates a new tNode with the
   given data and NULL left and right pointers. */
struct tNode* newtNode(int data)
{
  struct tNode* tNode = (struct tNode*)
                       malloc(sizeof(struct tNode));
  tNode->data = data;
  tNode->left = NULL;
  tNode->right = NULL;

  return(tNode);
}

/* Driver program to test above functions*/
int main()
{

  struct tNode *root = newtNode(5);
  root->left        = newtNode(6);
  root->right       = newtNode(7);
  root->left->left  = newtNode(8);
  root->left->right = newtNode(9);
  root->right->left = newtNode(10);
  root->right->right= newtNode(11);

  inOrder(root);

  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but Instead of creating node, i am looking  for direct array conversion into in-order binary tree array. .